# Can python generational garbage collector kick in before objet is released by reference counting

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection, reference-counting

In a CPython multithreaded environment, consider the following code

```
class Container:
    def __del__(self):
        # Some code that fails when run in a different thread than the thread that initialized this

def use_container():
    c = Container()
    # Some code

def thread():
    use_container()
```

We are running the function `thread` in its own thread. Under normal circumstances, when we call `use_container` and it returns, as the reference count for c will drop to zero, its `__del__` method is called. For a project I am working on, I suspect sometimes the `__del__` method is not called, or called by a different thread.

I know we should not rely on `__del__` being called. But under CPython, and when we are sure there are no reference cycles, are there any cases where `__del__` might not be called when the objects reference count gets to 0?

One possible case I'm considering is, right after `use_container` returns, garbage collector is kicked in in another thread before the interpreter releases the object, in turn garbage collector releases the object and calls its `__del__` method in another thread. Is such a case possible? And if so, what would happen in the original thread once it resumes execution?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but regarding your suspicion that "sometimes the \_\_del\_\_ method is...called by a different thread." I wouldn't _suspect_ it. I would _assume_ it. In some other programming languages (e.g., in Java) it's practically guaranteed that GC will happen in a dedicated GC thread. IMO any time it matters which thread calls some function, that's a strong [_code smell_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: @SolomonSlow this is a third party library I am using, which is releasing a lock when this object is deleted, that's why its important from which thread this is called. Probably done this way for ease of use, but I suspect its causing problems.

Comment: That's arguably a bug in the library. It should be using a context manager to acquire and release the lock, not depend on object lifetime semantics that aren't guaranteed between different Python implementations. (`__del__` isn't even guaranteed to be called; it may be skipped if the object is destroyed as part of interpreter shutdown).

Comment: @chepner that's correct, and I want to implement a solution with this thinking, I just want to be sure this could be the cause, but I could not think of a case how it could happen in my case. We are using CPython, which has reference counting, and this seems to happen while the application is running, so there is no interpreter shutdown. And I could not think of a case how the `__del__`  isn't called under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector runs on the main thread. Not the child threads. So there is no way that 1 thread will have a reference and a different thread will del the object. Since on the interpreter level it still has a ref count of 1.

What could happen is the object is moved to a different generation within the collector.

Say you have a reference to an object. that object gets put in generation 0. The collector can run but not collect the object since it is still referenced somewhere. If it does survive collection it gets moved to generation 1 which will be collected less often. If it survives the second round of collection it will move to generation 2 where it will be collected least often.

In other words, Depending on when the collector runs the object might well survive in memory for a while with a ref count of 0 because that object lives in the last generation. It will stay in memory until that generation is collected and only then its `__del__` will be called. Further reading about generations here: https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/#optimization-generations